# Como checar campo com javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma tela em que tem os estados de ordem de serviçp, quando essa ordem de serviço for 86, ela não pode ser alterada para 93, conforme segue na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se for alterado para 93, quando clicar no botão salvar, ele retornar uma mensagem de erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue meu código abaixo:

```
if(workOrderStateNew == "93") 
        {           
            var oGrid = scr.getGrid("WorkOrderOperation");
            var rowNum = oGrid.getRowCount();
            var oCOperationState = scr.getObject("COperationState");

            var array = [oGrid,rowNum,oCOperationState];

            if (rowNum > 0)
            {
                for(var i = 1; i <= rowNum; i++)
                {       
                    if(array[2] == "C")
                    {
                        console.log('erro no array 2')
                        gm.showMessage(gm.loadResString("ERRORWORKTYPEESTATE", "PREVENTIVA", workOrderStateNew), MSGICON.IconError);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Ele não está sendo executado quando clico em salvar, mesmo alterando para 93 ele não me retorna a mensagem de erro quando clico em salvar, ja dei console na minha condição e o console também não me retorna nada, o que pode ser?

A função vem da váriavel:

```
                   var workOrderState = selectSentence.selectCommandOneValue1T1W("workOrderState", "WorkOrder", "workOrder", scr.getValue("TBWorkOrder"), true );
```

Comment: Não está entrando no `if(workOrderStateNew == "93")`? De onde vem essa variável `workOrderStateNew`? Como ela é declarada?

Comment: @Sam fiz as edições

Comment: Precisava ver como como está declarada a função que contém o código `if(workOrderStateNew == "93")...` e as porções de código que invocam essa função, eventos, chamadas diretas e indiretas.